# Pin a website to the Start menu and then change its URL

Tags: windows, windows-10

How do we do the following?

1. Pin a website to the start menu.
2. Then, change the URL of the pinned website.

Sometimes the URL has a bunch of junk in it that we want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

## Pin a website to the Start Menu

1. Open Internet Explorer desktop app.
2. Go the website that you want to pin.
3. Click the gear icon and choose "Add site to Apps."
4. In the window that appears, click "Add."
5. Open the Start Menu, go to All apps, find the pinned site, right click it, and choose, "Pin to Start."

## Change the URL of the pinned website

Open PowerShell and run the following.

```
> cd "C:\Users\Ed\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu"
> dir -n
Programs
BigFont.website
> notepad BigFont.website
```

Notepad will open with the settings for the `.website` file. Change the `URL` field and save the file. You're done.

We can also do this with the command prompt.

## Notes

Instead of using the IE desktop app, we can use the new Edge browser, but it pins the site directly to the Start menu and stores the resultant `.website` file elsewhere.

Instead of using PowerShell, we can use the command prompt.

Once we have notepad open, we can also change tile's icon.

To change the tile's name, rename the `.website` file.